# Range selection error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a VBA-code under ThisWorkBook, so that code will run automatically when I open the Excel file. The code selects a dynamic range by using `xlDown`, then it will add a name to the workbook depending on the selection. Check the code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Sheets("sheet1").Range("E2", Sheets("sheet1").Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Select
     ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DateList", RefersTo:=Selection
End Sub
```

I am pretty sure that I am writing correctly, but I get an error message like this:

> Run time error '1004': Select method of Range Class failed

This error message is highlighting the second line:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("E2", Sheets("sheet1").Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Select
```

And when I use the same selection method to clear the same range, it works without error like below:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("E2", Sheets("sheet1").Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Clear
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select in the first row?

Comment: @Kathara the range starts from `E2` and it can finish anywhere in the same column like `E15` or `E20`, so it must be dynamic selection. And the content is just number, 6 digits number

Comment: Your `.Clear` process is probably running because `sheet1` is actually the active sheet at that point in time, so you can get away with not qualifying your range references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is data underneath that you ***don't*** want - I would go with `xlUp` instead to prevent an error when there is *only* a value in E2:

```
With Sheets("sheet1")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "DateList", .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
End With
```

Comment: I guess that your method first counts the total rows inside whole sheet `.Rows.Count,`, if there are 7 rows with data, then it becomes `.Cells(7, 5).End(xlUp)`. Then `xlUp` finds the first value upward which has a value? 
In that case, if there are other data in other columns, then I should specify `.Rows.Count` for the column 5, right?

Comment: `Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)` is the same as going to the last row in column E and pressing `Ctrl + Up` which would 'jump' to the next cell with data in _(which in theory is the end of your list)_ and returns that cell. If you only had a value in E2, then `xlDown` would result in the entire column E being set as the named range, whereas with `xlUp` just E2 would be the named range

Comment: yes, I tested it, and it happens like you said in case there is only one row data and if I use `xlDown`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
With Sheets("sheet1")
     ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "DateList", .Range("E2:E" & .[E:E].Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row)
End With
```

Comment: you would still need to qualify `[E2]` with the sheet object, so with a dot before them

Comment: @vasily  thanks a lot. it worked. Do you have any explanation why my method didn't work for `select` process, but it worked for `clear` process?

Comment: your code also will works fine if previously you will activate sheet1, the select method does not works if sheet does not activated

Comment: @Vasily thanks, now I remember that I am supposed to activate the selection first.